# In MATLAB how to write a structure that its fields are valued iteratively?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, iteration, structure

I have a problem with increasing the size of the structure iteratively. I could not find its solution.

What I need is to have 200 vectors (named EVE1-EVE200), as fields of a structure.
I wrote the following code in matlab:

```
 for i=1:200;
    events=struct(['EVE' num2str(i)],[]);
end
```

But it just forms the last structure.
Would anyone please help me? 
Is this way of initializing a data base is the best way anyways?

Comment: you are just creating a new structure with each loop, you are not appending to the previous struct you made.

Answer (score 5):

For what you ask for, it is best to use the following approach:

```
events = struct;
for i=1:200
    events.( ['EVE' num2str(i)] ) = [];
end
```

But why not use a cell array instead of a struct?

```
events = {};
for i=1:200
    events{i} = [];
end
```

The latter is much clearer and serves the same purpose.

Comment: Yes, variable variablenames is generally poor coding style, and `events{i}` is much better. +1 Andreas H.